# Avoid document.write()

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, document.write

I have tested my website with PageSpeed Insights and i have the following error: Avoid document.write(). I have on my website a javascript code used for tracking visitors:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" async>
document.write('<img src=\"https://traficwebsite/button.php?u=user&ref='+escape(document.referrer)+'&page='+escape(location.href.replace(/#.+$/,''))+'&rez='+screen.width+'x'+screen.height+'\" alt=\"DespreTrafic\" border=\"0\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" />');
</script>
```

How can i replace document.write in this code. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically change the src of an img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid using document.write() occurs when trying to load a dashboard page in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736040/avoid-using-document-write-occurs-when-trying-to-load-a-dashboard-page-in-chro)

Comment: it does not matter if you declare your script as async, document write is still blocking. It is bad practice to use it and both chrome and firefox will throw errors / warning upon evaluating it. You are not doing your users a favour neither since your code will be slow to execute, assuming you get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Recommended: Element.append()

You can create an element using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
That element can then be appended to `document.body`.

```js
// Create an <img>-element
var img = document.createElement('img');

// Configure the attributes of your element
img.alt = 'An alternative text';

// Append it
document.body.append(img);
```

## Element.innerHTML

You can add the String directly to the HTML using [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). However, as mentioned in the link, that makes your site vulnerable to script-execution when a script is inserted without using the `<script>`-tag.

Example of the vulnerability (hover over the image-element to see its effect):

```js
var altText = 'some text" onmouseover="(() => {console.log(\'This lambda was executed!\')})()';

// This will add the following:
// <img alt="some text" onmouseover="(() => {console.log('This lambda was executed!')})()">
document.body.innerHTML += '<img alt="' + altText + '">';
```

But if you are sure that the string you build is safe, you can add the contained element like this (replace the String-placeholder below with your String):

```js
document.body.innerHTML += '<img alt="Some text">';
```

```html
<p>I was here first!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend Element.innerHTML.
Editing Element.innerHTML removes some of the given events to elements (e.g. the VueJs application). Better to use document.body.append.